# Don't apply .htaccess rule for all directories

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule in my .htaccess allowing me the remove extension.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

How can I apply this only for the current directory and not for all others website in subfolders ?

Structure I have:

```
- public_html  <-- root
  - index.php  <-- must be apply
  - www        <-- mustn't be apply
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to your rule that excludes rewriting to subfolders :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```